# How to create a swipe to hit in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, physics, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I am in the processs of creating a "shape flicking" game of sorts for the iOS platform. I am using Apple's Sprite Kit and I would like the most efficient and least performance costly approach to have the ability to "flick" the various shapes off the screen.

My first thought would be to have an invisible circular physics body that follows your finger whenever you swipe or touch the screen, but I think there may be an easier way by applying an impulse..any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hit objects with finger movement in Sprite Kit, Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300365/how-to-hit-objects-with-finger-movement-in-sprite-kit-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for here in the link below..question was already answered!

[How to hit objects with finger movement in Sprite Kit, Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300365/how-to-hit-objects-with-finger-movement-in-sprite-kit-objective-c)