# Sprite Kit how to have a specific node in a grid perform an action?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, nodes, sprite

I have 25 identical sprites in one category spread out in my scene, created with a for-loop. I want to be able to click one specific sprite to, for example, start rotating that sprite. Would I have to make nonatomic properties for every node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300365/how-to-hit-objects-with-finger-movement-in-sprite-kit-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `- (SKNode *)nodeAtPoint:(CGPoint)p` method of `SKNode` (a class from which `SKScene` inherits) to pin-point a specific node. Say you have 25 random nodes about the screen and you want to make one of them perform an action, you would have to find the touch location, then locate the node in that position, then make it perform an action.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *specificNode = [self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
    // make specificNode perform some SKAction
}
```

Comment: It turns out that my code did actually work. I just mixed up two variables. Your answer cleared it up for me, thank you very much.